# Верстка меню

Tags: html, css

Каким образом лучше сверстать меню такого вида, как на картинке?
[image]
При этом и картинка над пунктом меню, и сам пункт меню должны являться ссылкой.
Верстка на html5, то есть код вида

```
<nav>
    <a href="/" class="menu" title="">О нас</a>
    <a href="/" class="menu" title="">Опции</a>
    <a href="/" class="menu" title="">Контакты</a>
</nav>
```

Не могу разобраться, как лучше сделать так, чтобы и картинка, и текст были ссылками.
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А вы пробовали,сделать бакграунд для ссылок

```
<style>
a.menu { background-image: url(туттвоякартинка.jpg); }
</style>
```

Comment: а разве картинка тогда будет ссылкой, если поставить её в бэкграунд? сейчас попробую.

Comment: Попробуйте

Comment: а вообще да, вроде работает.  спасибо)

Comment: Пожалуйста)